# Where can I learn about connections between economics and physics?

Tags: resource-recommendations, econo-physics

I understand that there are a lot of concepts in economics motivated by physics so I was wondering if anyone would be able to recommend me some sources to learn about these things. Ideally, a textbook so I can do learn it elaborately but anything should be good. I am really looking for the economics motivated by statistical physics as well if anyone knows anything about that.

Answer (score 8):

I only encountered the subject in "Stochastic Processes, from Physics to Finance" Paul, Baschnagel.

It is not a rigorous book, but it requires no previous experience with stochastic processes. Actually I would consider it a good introduction to stochastic processes. I found all the physics presented prior to the finance section to be interesting and relevant.

(Maybe this is not a proper answer, but I do not have enough rep to comment.)
:/